# Riak secondary indexes not preserved using Java client when copying keys cross-cluster

Tags: java, riak

So I am copying a bunch of data from Riak cluster A (1.4 cluster) to Riak cluster B (2.0 cluster) due to a bunch of annoying (and irrelevant to my problem) environment constraints making it not possible to upgrade the cluster any other way.

I am using the Java 1.4 Riak client to talk to both clusters.  I read in the key from my 1.4 cluster, and - keeping the exact same IRiakObject - write it out to the 2.0 cluster.

If I run this in a debugger and inspect said IRiakObject, I see that secondary indices are in fact populated on this object.

But when I actually run this, I see that the 2.0 cluster does not accept the secondary indexes - they come back empty when I do a GET on the 2.0 cluster for this key.

What am I doing wrong?

Sample code is below.  Note this is assembled from Scala but it's using the Java library.  Note that sourceRiakClient and destRiakClient do not correspond to the same server. (getBucket and cloneBucket are methods I wrote.)

```
val srcBucket : Bucket = getBucket(sourceRiakClient, bucketName)
val destBucket: Bucket = cloneBucket(destRiakClient, bucketName, srcBucket)
val value: IRiakObject = bucket.fetch(key).execute()
destBucket.store(key, value.getValue).withoutFetch().execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by calling value.getValue, I am turning my IRiakObject into a byte[] and that stripped off the secondary index information.  When I simply store the value itself, I get the behavior I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Is the other cluster configured to use the Leveldb backend? By default 2.0 uses Bitcask. Bitcask does not support secondary indexes.

Comment: Yes, it is configured to use leveldb.